# Add a custom button on the admin screen of Broadleaf and provide action for it.

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, broadleaf-commerce

I want to create a new tab in the order column (Cancellation tab) at Broadleaf admin screen.
In that I want to create an HTML page which will have a cancel button.Once the button is clicked, I want certain information to get loaded in the related database table.

Please help me with creating a new tab, HTML page inside it and creating an action button on it.

Regarding Creatng a new tab. I have created an annotations as follows in OrderImpl domain class:

@OneToOne(targetEntity = OrderCancellationImpl.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CANCELLATIONID")
    @AdminPresentation(friendlyName = "OrderImpl_OrderCancellation", tab = Presentation.Tab.Name.Cancel, tabOrder = Presentation.Tab.Order.Cancel)
    protected OrderCancellation orderCancellation;

tab name and tab order--> I have given a particular tab name and its order value.

But it doesnt create a new tab. Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would not normally add @AdminPresentation to a *ToOne relationship. This annotation is generally relegated to "primitive" field types. This explains why you didn't see any result in the admin.

Comment: As for a custom action that applies to an entire entity, we would generally handle that with an EntityFormAction (and in your case, custom .js) injected via a FormBuilderExtensionHandler. I know that's not specifically the solution you asked for, but I felt compelled to mention an alternative, since we generally handle this requirement differently.